# Tomcat automatically forwards to a certain page. Cannot find settings

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I have been using Tomcat 6.0 on Eclipse and every project that I run with it sends me to a certain page when you type in just the domain. I can't seem to find the settings for this!

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

will forward me to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/mtms/account/login.orh
```

Typing a specific path will take me to the specified path

This works fine (different project)

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/phoneTable
```

I have tried looking for where "/mtms/account/login.orh" may be defined, but I cannot seem to find it. I have looked through server.xml, context.xml, catalina.properties and web.xml in Servers to no avail.

My predecessor left the company and now I can't find where he set this setting.

Where should I be looking?

Comment: Please validate welcome file in `web.xml`.

Comment: Run you application in Firefox and look at the Firefox Firebug plugin console at `Net` tab to find out where there request is going.

Comment: IE8 and FF does not forward me as well. Only Chrome does. I did not add any browser specific conditions. I believe it is a server-side configuration that is doing this..

Comment: server-side configuration on the basis of browser? I don't think so. The issue is with Chrome only. Any JavaScript issue because JavaScript works differently on different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

**Firefox Firebug plugin** can help you to monitor the requested URLs.

- Please validate `welcome-file-list` in `web.xml`.
- Is there any `filter-mapping` is defined in `web.xml`.
- Is there any `login-config` or other security defined in `web.xml`.

> As its redirecting for Login hence there must be some authentication is applied in your applicaion.

Snapshots:

[image]

Comment: This is going to sound strange, but Firefox doesn't forward me to "http://127.0.0.1:8080/mtms/account/login.orh" only Chrome does. When I type in "http:127.0.0.1:8080/" for FF it will just give me a 404.

Comment: Additionally there is nothing special in the web.xml welcome-file-list(default: index.html, htm, jsp), or filter-mapping(commented out).

Comment: Is there any browser specific check in your application? Try with IE also.

Comment: Put some debug/alset in `index.html/htm/jsp` to find the cause. It will tell you that actually request is going to welcome page or not. If not then there is some default filter-mapping or authentication servlet is coming into picture.

Answer (score -1):

The tomcat server picks the default page as ROOT application in the webapps folder. I think that should help. In that check the index.html or index.jsp file. There must be some change in the redirect url.
This link may help:
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.kieranlane.com/2013/12/07/redirecting-tomcat-default-home-page/&safe=active

Comment: Also the web.xml of the application will help.